# Create a grid on top of an image

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I hope you are all well and safe.

In NodeJS, I wanted to create a grid on top of an image. Like this:

[Image without grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVZQx.png)

[Image with grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Rjs.png)

Can someone tell me, please, how can I achieve this (some library or something)?

After creating the grid, I would like to go square by square and check the information for each square. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: What kind of information do you want to check square by square?

Comment: Hi. For example, the color of each square.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer has a native Cairo dependency... Below I used pureimage  instead, which has Pure JS implementations of jpeg and png encoding.

```
static drawParallel = (canvas, step, isYAxis) => {
  const c2d = canvas.getContext('2d')
  const numberOfSteps = (canvas.width / step) | 0
  const end = isYAxis ? canvas.height : canvas.width
  console.log(`Steps: ${numberOfSteps}\n`)
  c2d.lineWidth = 1.1 // PureImage hides thin lines
  c2d.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,192,203,0.69)'
  for (let i = 1; i < numberOfSteps; i++) {
    const from = i * step
    const to = i * step
    const mx = isYAxis ? [from, 0, to, end] : [0, from, end, to]
    console.log(`Stroking ${mx[0]}, ${mx[1]} to ${mx[2]}, ${mx[3]}`)
    c2d.beginPath()
    c2d.moveTo(mx[0], mx[1])
    c2d.lineTo(mx[2], mx[3])
    c2d.stroke()
  }
}
```

[image]

source: https://stackblitz.com/edit/feathersjs-7kqlyt

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas). You can use it for all sorts of image jobs and editing. For example, you could get a transparent PNG image of the grid and lay it on:

```
const Canvas = require("canvas");
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(619, 319);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let img = await Canvas.loadImage("./path/to/image.png");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

let grid = await Canvas.loadImage("./path/to/grid.png");
ctx.drawImage(grid, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
```

I myself managed to get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3AxR.png).